# How to determine which processes are currently running

Tags: ios, instruments

I'm trying to use Instruments to figure out what in my app is eating up all my battery life.

I thought Time Profiler would work here, but I can't figure out how to get it to tell me what processes are running *after* a certain point in time. Currently, Time Profiler tells me about all the tasks that have run since the app first launched, but I only want to know about the ones that are running right now.

Is there any way to filter Time Profiler in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - hold down the option key while dragging across the timeline.